# jquery .on() behaving weird

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('li.sleeve span.zoom-in').on 'click', -> #1
    $(this).removeClass('zoom-in').addClass('zoom-out')
    $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('flip').css('z-index', 99)
    $card = $(this).parents('.card')
    offset = $card.offset()
    $card.animate {
      top: '-='+(offset.top-30)
      left: '-='+(offset.left-50)
    }, 100

  $(document).on 'click', 'li.sleeve span.zoom-out', -> #2
    alert 'hi!'
    $sleeve = $(this).parents('.sleeve')
    $(this).removeClass('zoom-out').addClass('zoom-in')
    $sleeve.toggleClass('flip')
    $card = $(this).parents('.card')
    $card.animate {
      top: 0
      left: 0
    }, 1000, ->
      $sleeve.css('z-index', 3)
```

http://cardbinder.herokuapp.com/card_sets/avacyn-restored/cards - if you click on a zoom button, some weird stuff is happening. At first, the `$(document).on 'click'` was `$('li.sleeve span.zoom-out').on 'click'`, but that doesn't work since `.on()` only plays nicely with objects that are in the dom when the page is loaded. Hence the `$(document)` which has typically worked for me in the past.

Bottom line, method #2 is firing as soon as #1 is. Hopefully you can help me figure out why.

Comment: There are. All the cards have that at first. Then that class is toggled with the initial click

Comment: The 1st click is supposed to make the card bigger. Then stay bigger until the 2nd click.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is changing, `$('li.sleeve span.zoom-out').on 'click'` into something like `$('body').on 'click', 'li.sleeve span.zoom-out', ->`.. Because the first one only attach the handler when the page is loaded and the second one will attach the handler into anything that matched the element.. It's something like [$.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)..

Comment: I wanted this to be the answer... same effect, though.

Comment: If you could, please make a likely example in JSFiddle so we can directly change the code there..

Answer (score 0):

Since your element is part of the document, when you click it, you are also clicking the document, so the document click event will also fire.

Comment: but aren't I limiting it to the scope of `li.sleeve span.zoom-out` within the document? that's the whole point of the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the doc,](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handlers are fired in their declaration order. We might assume by a linear search in the event list. So:

- You have a first handler attached on `document` which matches class `zoom-in`. It is fired when you click your item.
- You change the class of your item from `zoom-in` to `zoom-out`. Do some more job and the handler finishes
- jQuery continues examining the other handlers at `document` level able to respond to a `click` event. Up to the one that responds to a `click` in a `zoom-out` object. As the object class *now* matches, it is executes in its turn.

From the outside, #1 and #2 where fired in a row.

Couldn't you simply swap the two "on-click" handlers in your code? Attaching "on click zoom-out" first would break that behavior. IMHO.

If that doesn't work, a more crude way to block event propagation would be to call [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) in the #1 handler.